# How can I calculate the average of the GPAs in the function?

Tags: python, algorithm, math

In the program, I want to first read only the score of each person from the csv file, and then in the function, first calculate the average of each person, and then calculate the average of all grades.

```
csv file:
mandana,5,7,3,15
hamid,3,9,4,20,9,1,8,16,0,5,2,4,7,2,1
sina,19,10,19,6,8,14,3
sara,0,5,20,14
soheila,13,2,5,1,3,10,12,4,13,17,7,7
ali,1,9
sarvin,0,16,16,13,19,2,17,8
```

```
my code:

import csv

from statistics import mean

def sss():
     with open(r'C:\Users\Mobin\Desktop\test_project\reders.csv') as js:
        s = csv.reader(js)
        ld = []
        for l in s:
            ld.append(l[1:])
        print(mean(ld))
sss()
```

```
output:
8.401530612244898
```

Please help me write the program

Comment: My code has a problem, please help me correct code and complete the program

Comment: If possible, please write your explanation in the answer field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may helps you:

```
import csv
from statistics import mean

def avg(row):
    row = [ int(x) for x in row[1:] ]
    return mean(row)

csv_file = csv.reader(open('reders.csv'))

for row in csv_file:
    print(row[0], avg(row))
```

Ouput:

```
mandana 7.5
hamid 6.066666666666666
sina 11.285714285714286
sara 9.75
soheila 7.833333333333333
ali 5
sarvin 11.375
```